# Loading SVG file using esbuild

Tags: typescript, svg, electron, react-typescript, esbuild

I am using electron with typescript react, and using esbuild bundler.

Project File Tree:

```
projectname/
┣ assets/
┃ ┣ index.d.ts
┃ ┗ logo.svg
┣ src/
┃ ┣ components/
┃ ┃ ┗ Intro.tsx
┃ ┣ App.tsx
┃ ┣ electron.ts
┃ ┣ fonts.css
┃ ┣ index.css
┃ ┣ index.html
┃ ┗ index.tsx
┣ .gitignore
┣ build.js
┣ LICENSE
┣ package.json
┣ README.md
┗ yarn.lock
```

I tried to use esbuild-plugin-svg, but this error came out.

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'esbuild-plugin-svg'.
> 'd:/genius0412/github/checkaccess/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-svg/src/index.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/esbuild-plugin-svg` if it exists or add a new declaration
> (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'esbuild-plugin-svg';`ts(7016)

Also, I tried to use esbuild-plugin-svgj, but it did not work either.

> error: Could not resolve "react" (the plugin "svgj" didn't set a
> resolve directory)

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's a typescript issue - it doesn't know what type is imported with:

```
import logo from '../assets/logo.svg';
```

I see you try to add types with `index.d.ts`. As your index file is `.tsx` I would try importing the `index.t.ts` manually in the `index.tsx` - at some point I've got an impression that TS import `d.ts` automatically for `.js` files, but not for `.ts`

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

I added

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

to the project's `declaration.d.ts` file.

Then in `build.cjs` I added a loader for SVG files:

```
build({
  ...
  loader: {'.svg': 'text'},
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`'.svg': 'text'` didn't work for me, this did:

```
  build({
    ...
    loader: {
      '.png': 'dataurl',
      '.svg': 'dataurl'
    },
    ...
  })
```

And I am using svg images in `.tsx` like this:

```
  import mySvgLogo from '~/assets/my-svg-logo.svg'
  <img src={mySvgLogo}></img>
```